# Problema Asignar foco a un widget en tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Mediante el click en un botón de tkinter le asigno estratégicamente el foco a otro widget de una ventana. En el mismo flujo del evento del botón pido saber cual tiene el foco y me dice que es el botón accionado quien tiene el foco. Sin embargo, aunque al dar click el botón (el cual obviamente tiene el foco de manera inmediata) luego se lo asigno a otro widget.

Luego de la ejecución se puede ver en la ventana que el otro widget tiene el foco para escribir con teclado (es un `entry`) pero durante la ejecución siempre dice que es el botón.
¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Hola Andrés, estaría bien que pudieras aportar el código o al menos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable que muestre y permita reproducir el problema.  ¿A qué te refieres con "después de la ejecución"? ¿De la ejecucion de la callback del botón o de otra cosa? ¿El Entry y el botón están en la misma ventana?